# Virtual Directory and Web Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-services, iis

Can somebody shed some light on virtual directories in IIS, and why when i try to load a web service project, visual studio prompts me to create virtual directory.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because in the solution, the project for the web site was added as "Add Existing Web Site" from "Local IIS" or from "Remote Site". The solution is expecting an actual virtual directory to exist. You could remove the project and re-add it, but from the "File System". I think that'll sort you out.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the Web Site "project" type with web services. Instead, use File->New Project and create a Web Application Project.